# How to verify one date is bigger than the other in my MVC model through attributes?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following in my model code

```
    [Required]
    public DateTime? PreferredShowDate1 { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PreferredShowDate2 { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PreferredShowDate3 { get; set; }
```

now, i want to make sure that PreferredShowDate1 < PreferredShowDate2 < PreferredShowDate3
and none of the 3 dates are the same.

Is it possible to do this in the model code? Can i do this?

```
//put in some code in attribute to compare preferredShowDate2 with preferredShowDate1      
[compare]
public DateTime? PreferredShowDate2 { get; set; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to do it on your own. This "column-spanning-logic" is not supported oob

Answer (score 5):

Check out foolproof validation

http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

gives you access to a greaterthan/lessthan validation attribute as well as a host of useful other ones

Comment: Nice link, too bad I didn't know about these before as I think I have hand-written at least 1/3 of those!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IValidatableObject interface to perform this kind of validation.

```
public class MyClass : IValidatableObject
{
    public DateTime? PreferredShowDate1 { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PreferredShowDate2 { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PreferredShowDate3 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    //Example compare stuff. Your needs may vary.
    if ((DateTime.Compare(PreferredShowDate1, PreferredShowDate2) < 0) && 
     (DateTime.Compare(PreferredShowDate2, PreferredShowDate3) < 0))
    {
         yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid Date", new[] { "PreferredShowDate1" });
    }
}
```